# Validating a txt file

Tags: java, validation

I have to validate and extract strings of code from a text document based on the format below.

```
Title: title
YLabel: YLabel
XLabel: XLabel
XStart: numeric value
XInterval: numeric value
3.5, 5, 7, 9..etc
```

I need to capture all intances of data and validate according to this modal. I tried using the .split() function but got confused.
Here's what I have so far:

```
public boolean validateFile(String info) {
    // split all the words and trim commas/whitespaces
    String[] validate = info.split("\\s"); 
    for(int i=0; i<validate.length; i++) {
        if(validate[i].equals("XStart:") || validate[i].equals("XInterval:")) {
            try {
                double d = Double.parseDouble(validate[i+1]);
                info += validate[i+1]+" ";
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException x) {
                info = "invalid file format";
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here info has all the data extracted from the text file. And end result would be the first two numeric values. But how can I validate if a file is true to it's format or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array of property names, so you may handle all generic.

Hold the model, the form:

```
String[] properties = {"YLabel", "XLabel", ...};
```

Split the info in lines:

```
String[] lines = info.split("\r?\n"); // Split on line end
if (lines.length != properties.length + 1) {
    return false;
}

for (int lineno = 0; lineno < properties.length; ++lineno) {
    if (!lines[lineno].startsWith(properties[lineno] + ":")) {
        return false;
    }
}

String values = ... and the rest using split("\\s+").
```